# Select User Name in Access Query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access DB that I want to capture the user's name when they open it. I have created a function to return the user name lifted from another Stack Overflow question:

```
Function UserNameWindows() As String
     UserName = Environ("USERNAME")
     Debug.Print UserName
End Function
```

This works in that I can see my user name in the immediate window. However, when I try and query this I get nothing back - no user name and no error message.

```
    INSERT INTO tblUser(UserName,Logindate)
SELECT UserNameWindows(),  Date()   ;
```

I'm using Access 2016. The date goes into the log table but not the user's name; any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the name of your function to the value of username. Your bug is a typo. See the small edit below:

```
Function UserNameWindows() As String
     UserNameWindows = Environ("USERNAME")
     Debug.Print UserName
End Function
```